# PHP PDO, Ubuntu, MDBTools Problems connecting to Access Database

Tags: php, ubuntu, pdo, ms-access-2010, mdbtools

I am having trouble debugging a connection to an MSAccess 2010 .accdb file.

I'm running a Scotch Box Vagrant vm (v3.5) and have installed the MDBTools odbc driver via `sudo apt-get install mdbtools`.

My `/etc/odbcinst.ini` file looks like this:

```
# To enable unixODBC tracing, add this section to odbcinst.ini.
# Include the [ODBC] section heading.
[ODBC]
Trace = yes
TraceFile = /var/www/unixODBC.log

[MDBTools]
Description=MDBTools Driver
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmdbodbc.so
Setup=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmdbodbc.so
FileUsage=1
UsageCount=1
```

I've also created a datasource in /etc/odbc.ini

```
[CONTACTS]
Driver = MDBTools
Description = Contacts Database
Database = /data/contacts-db.accdb
Server = localhost
```

The test php file I'm using to attempt a connection is called `testMSACCESS.php` and looks like this:

```
<?php
try {
    $dbFile = '/data/contacts-db.accdb';
    echo 'Does file exist at ' . $dbFile . '? ';
    var_dump(file_exists($dbFile));
    var_dump(file_exists($dbFile));
    echo 'Is the file readable ? ';
    var_dump(is_readable($dbFile));
    echo 'Is the file writable ? ';
    var_dump(is_writable($dbFile));
    $dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver=MDBTools;DBQ={$dbFile};");
    // or $dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver=MDBTools;DSN=CONTACTS;");
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    if ($dbh){
        echo "success <br/>";
    }
    $dbh = null;
}catch (Exception $e){
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'Exception caught: could not connect to database.' . PHP_EOL;
    echo (string) $e;
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

The db file, `contacts-db.accdb`, is in a dir at the root of the machine `/data`.

When I try to connect by loading the script in a browser, the Exception thrown looks like this:

```
Does file exist at /data/contacts-db.accdb? bool(true)
Is the file readable ? bool(true)
Is the file writable ? bool(true)
Exception caught: could not connect to database.
PDOException: SQLSTATE[00000] SQLDriverConnect: 0  in /var/www/public/testMSACCESS.php:6
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/public/testMSACCESS.php(6): PDO->__construct('odbc:Driver=MDB...')
#1 {main}
```

When running the script via the cmd line, I get a bit more info:

```
vagrant@scotchbox:~$ php /var/www/public/testMSACCESS.php 
Does file exist at /data/contacts-db.accdb? bool(true)
Is the file readable ? bool(true)
Is the file writable ? bool(true)
Unknown Jet version.
File not found
Unable to locate database /data/contacts-db.accdb
<pre>Exception caught: could not connect to database.
PDOException: SQLSTATE[00000] SQLDriverConnect: 0  in /var/www/public/testMSACCESS.php:6
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/public/testMSACCESS.php(6): PDO->__construct('odbc:Driver=MDB...')
#1 {main}</pre>
```

And this is what the unixODBC trace log looks like:

```
[ODBC][1515][1536073973.983218][__handles.c][460]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            Environment = 0x5591139d5d60
[ODBC][1515][1536073973.985108][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][189]
        Entry:
            Environment = 0x5591139d5d60
            Attribute = SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION
            Value = 0x3
            StrLen = 0
[ODBC][1515][1536073973.985588][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][363]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][1515][1536073973.990811][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][189]
        Entry:
            Environment = 0x5591139d5d60
            Attribute = SQL_ATTR_CP_MATCH
            Value = (nil)
            StrLen = 0
[ODBC][1515][1536073973.991928][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][363]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][1515][1536073973.992707][SQLAllocHandle.c][375]
        Entry:
            Handle Type = 2
            Input Handle = 0x5591139d5d60
[ODBC][1515][1536073973.993173][SQLAllocHandle.c][493]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            Output Handle = 0x5591139d6400
[ODBC][1515][1536073973.993682][SQLSetConnectAttr.c][396]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x5591139d6400
            Attribute = SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT
            Value = 0x1
            StrLen = -6
[ODBC][1515][1536073973.994129][SQLSetConnectAttr.c][681]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][1515][1536073973.994892][SQLSetConnectAttr.c][396]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x5591139d6400
            Attribute = SQL_ATTR_ODBC_CURSORS
            Value = (nil)
            StrLen = -6
[ODBC][1515][1536073973.995351][SQLSetConnectAttr.c][681]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][1515][1536073973.995872][SQLDriverConnect.c][726]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x5591139d6400
            Window Hdl = (nil)
            Str In = [Driver=MDBTools;DBQ=/var/www/public/contacts-db.accdb;][length = 54]
            Str Out = 0x7ffdb1be6d00
            Str Out Max = 1023
            Str Out Ptr = 0x7ffdb1be6cf8
            Completion = 0
        UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'ISO8859-1' and UNICODE 'UCS-2LE'

[ODBC][1515][1536073974.001199][SQLDriverConnect.c][1353]
        Exit:[SQL_ERROR]
[ODBC][1515][1536073974.001731][SQLGetDiagRec.c][680]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x5591139d6400
            Rec Number = 1
            SQLState = 0x7f11dce6c010
            Native = 0x7f11dce6c218
            Message Text = 0x7f11dce6c016
            Buffer Length = 511
            Text Len Ptr = 0x7ffdb1be688a
[ODBC][1515][1536073974.002167][SQLGetDiagRec.c][717]
        Exit:[SQL_NO_DATA]
[ODBC][1515][1536073974.002707][SQLEndTran.c][421]
        Entry:                
            Connection = 0x5591139d6400                
            Completion Type = 1
[ODBC][1515][1536073974.003125][SQLEndTran.c][433]Error: 08003
[ODBC][1515][1536073974.003551][SQLDisconnect.c][208]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x5591139d6400
[ODBC][1515][1536073974.004006][SQLDisconnect.c][237]Error: 08003
[ODBC][1515][1536073974.004462][SQLFreeHandle.c][284]
        Entry:
            Handle Type = 2
            Input Handle = 0x5591139d6400
[ODBC][1515][1536073974.004999][SQLFreeHandle.c][333]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][1515][1536073974.005544][SQLFreeHandle.c][219]
        Entry:
            Handle Type = 1
            Input Handle = 0x5591139d5d60
```

I can see where the failure is happening in the trace, `[SQLDriverConnect.c][726]` and `[SQLDriverConnect.c][1353]`. It appears to be a connection error, but I cannot make sense of the information contained in the following block in the trace log, `[SQLGetDiagRec.c][680]`.

Also, I don't understand why the database can't be found if PHP can find it or why it would say it doesn't know the Jet Engine version since the file was created with an 8 year old version of MS Access (2010).

If anyone has any ideas as to how to debug the error I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: It seems you are attempting to connect to MS Access over Apache? Curious, try connecting to database using PHP outside of the web server. Be sure to specify full directory path (not relative to PHP script).

Comment: Thanks @Parfait . Yep, trying to connect using PHP+Apache. Will try connecting via cmd line and will update my question with the results.

Comment: I meant try running the PHP-MS Access outside of Apache. Specifically, do not place it web server folders. Place .accdb in an offline directory and test. Also, `DBQ` arg should not have curly braces.

Comment: See this very [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090172/dsn-less-connection-with-php-odbc-using-mdbtools-driver) with [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10788929/1422451). Looks like you have to try creating a DSN and connect through that instead of direct driver.

Comment: @Parfait, I am still not getting any luck. Also, the curly braces are PHP string substitution syntax. You wrap a var name in them when you use a var within a double-quoted string, so the final connection string would not have them.

Comment: better add ODBC tables into the `.acdb` file and use mySQL as the backend, for both... and maybe read the log files instead of just posting them here, it clearly reads `Unable to locate database /data/contacts-db.accdb` (user `apache:apache` might need read/write permissions); when open basedir is not being activated (not recommended to activate), it cannot read outside of the web-root either.

Comment: @MartinZeitler, using MySQL may not be an option, but I will investigate. Also, I've tried with the DB within the web root and ensuring that the file does have the correct permissions and still no luck. I'm considering rebuilding MDBTools from source as I found this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/brianb/mdbtools/issues/77) that seems to indicate someone had luck "rolling their own." Will update this question when I have time to dedicate to building from source.